# Facebook OpenGraph and Asp.Net application

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-opengraph

We want to add open graph functionality to our facebook app. I've following the tutorial on facebook.com with simple cook recipe application. It is work ok when i use just simple .html page for open graph object, and put this page on public hosting. Then i try to implement it in our asp.net application (it serves like a wrapper for flash game for facebook). I've add opengraphtest.aspx webform, added all neccesary metatags and scripts from tutorial. And now when i use debug tool, i have warnings:

[image: Debug tool screenshot:]

I've correct image dimensions, correct title and type tags:

```
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="557295941002570" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"   content="myappnamespace:recipe" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"    content="http://apps.facebook.com/myappnamespace/opengraphtest.aspx" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"  content="Sample Recipe Test" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"  content="http://mywebsite.com/og/cook.png" />
```

As a result of this warnings i can't test this integration, every time i post action response is returned with error:

```
"(#3502) Object at URL http://apps.facebook.com/myappnamespace/opengraphtest.aspx has og:type of 'website'. The property 'recipe' requires an object of og:type 'myappnamespace:recipe'. "
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a valid meta og:type to your app, like website.
You could see the valid object types here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/built-in-objects/

Comment: Thank you for response red_alert. The meta tags described in linked resource is built-in objects, but open graph allows custom objects, and both are valid og:type, as described in facebook tutorial.